# Question about a use of the imparfait

Tags: temps-grammatical

"Non Obélix. Tu n'auras pas de potion magique. Je t'ai dit mille fois que tu étais tombé dedans étant petit."

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but please can someone explain to me this usage of the imperfect tense. Assuming obelix falling into the potion was a one-off event, why is it not "Tu es tombé dedans"?

I asked a French person and they said it seems natural but they couldn't explain why.

Comment: This is not "imparfait" tense with « étais », this is "plus-que-parfait" with « étais tombé »

Answer (score 1):

It's not the *imparfait*, it's the *plus-que-parfait* of the verb *tomber*. It's close to the *passé composé* in its uses, it's for one-off events too.

The reason of using it, is that it's in the past compared to another event.

*Présent* and *passé composé*

> J'entre dans le salon. Je constate qu'il **a laissé** la télé allumée.

*Passé composé* and *plus-que-parfait*

> Je suis entré dans le salon. J'ai constaté qu'il **avait laissé** la télé allumée.

*Passé simple* and *plus-que-parfait*

> J'entrai dans le salon. Je constatai qu'il **avait laissé** la télé allumée.

*Imparfait* and *plus-que-parfait*

> J'entrais dans le salon. Je constatais qu'il **avait laissé** la télé allumée.

It's an event in the past compared to the narrative time. So it's like *even more in the past* if the narrative time is already in the past.

But there is more to say about the tenses, they have many uses so it's hard to explain everything (you can tell a past event with *futur antérieur* for example, yeah).

But the reason in your example is that it's a past event compared to *je t'ai dit* which is already a past event (past events in this case, one thousand it seems).

Would *Je t'ai dit mille fois que tu es tombé dedans étant petit* be wrong? Not at all. I even prefer this one.

Ah, tenses...

Comment: I think I understand. I've heard of plus-que-parfait but I've not studied it properly. Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Simon Déchamps about the fact that the tens is "plus-que-parfait" and is used to show an anteriority with respect to a past tense (the event (falling) happened before I told you). This is called "concordance des temps" in French if you want more information.

However, don't quite agree with 'Je t'ai dit mille fois que tu es tombé dedans étant petit' being better. IMHO, if the first sentence is in the past, it is better to use **plus-que-parfait** for anteriority.